# How to make every element in flex-box equal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

So i have a bootstrap pagination and because there can be longer numbers they have bigger width, i want each element to be equal width or every element to be the width of the the biggest one.

[This pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqkFA.png)

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">1</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">2</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">3</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">11</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">13</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can that by using `flex-grow` property.

```css
.page-item {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item">
      <button class="page-link text-dark"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <button class="page-link text-dark">1</button>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <button class="page-link text-dark">2</button>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <button class="page-link text-dark">3</button>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <button class="page-link text-dark">11</button>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <button class="page-link text-dark">13</button>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <button class="page-link text-dark"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a `flex-basis` and make `.page-link` to width 100%

```css
.page-item{
   flex: 0 1 40px;
}

.page-link{
 width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">1</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">2</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">3</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">11</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark">13</button>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <button class="page-link text-dark"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What does mean magic number 40px? When fixed width 40px that won't work larger pagination number (e.g. 1000)...

Comment: sanriot is right, what if i had numbers even bigger than 99, i need my pagination dynamically change to fit bigger numbers and at the same time be equally sized

Comment: Since it is not known the maximum size that the item will have, you must put a base value (flex-basis) that works with most, if a much larger value appears, it should increase its size  https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/0p4gr2ca/

Comment: Agree with that, but what if i had numbers like 97, 98, 99, 100, 101 so first 3 elements will be smaller than two last, i just want them to be equal size, here for example all elements the size of element with number 100 or 101